# PythonAnywhere install new module for 2.7

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I"m trying to install html2text using the command below:

```
>>pip install --username html2text
```

and I keep getting 'syntax error' and an arrow pointing to the last "l" in "install"...

Comment: This is an unfinished question and it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Progo - I think OP was asking in the clearest way they could, and several ppl have managed to figure out the answer...  the hint was in the chevrons.

Answer (score 6):

This would happen when you run this command in the python console.

DEMO

```
$ python
>>> pip install
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install --username html2text
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install --username html2text
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exit()
$
```

Exit from the python console, and run it outside the python shell at an OS command prompt

Here are a list of valid options: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#options May be you mean `--upgrade` ?

Comment: As per Glenn's comment below, the "--username" flag is almost certainly meant to be "--user".  The question is tagged "pythonanywhere", which is a Python hosting environment that doesn't provide root access, and the "--user" flag works around that by installing Python packages in a subdirectory of your home directory.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be run from Bash, not Python and the correct command you're looking for is:

```
pip install --user html2text
```

The --user is literal, and not a placeholder for your username.

Answer (score 1):

Pip does not have a flag called `--username`. I have just checked with the manual for the Python package installer (`usr$ man pip`).

try:

```
sudo pip install html2text
```